# Cannot install Vaadin plugin on Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers 2022-09

Tags: eclipse, vaadin

On a brand new installation of Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers 2022-09 I cannot install the Vaadin plugin for Eclipse.  It looks like Vaadin is incompatible with the m2e packages that come with Eclipse:

[image]

Comment: There seems to be an open issue for this on the Vaadin Eclipse plug-in github - [here](https://github.com/vaadin/eclipse-plugin/issues/807)