# Unable to create a view in Eclipse using New -> Other -> Vaadin -> New > Vaadin 10+ Design

Tags: eclipse, view, frontend, vaadin

I am evaluating Vaadin and I create a spring boot project with Vaadin dependency.
I imported my project in Eclipse and on the folder frontend/src/views, followign the documentation https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/tools/designer/getting-started/build-your-main-view, I did : New -> Other -> Vaadin -> New > Vaadin 10+ Design -> Next.
Each time I click on Next, I got the following error :

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath[] org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade.getCompileSourceLocations()'
at com.vaadin.designer2.eclipse.util.SourceFolderUtils.getSourceRootFolder(SourceFolderUtils.java:170)
at com.vaadin.designer2.eclipse.wizards.NewFlowWizardPage.getJavaSourcePath(NewFlowWizardPage.java:511)
at com.vaadin.designer2.eclipse.wizards.NewFlowWizardPage.initializeCompanionFileLocation(NewFlowWizardPage.java:506)
at com.vaadin.designer2.eclipse.wizards.NewFlowWizardPage.initializeFieldsWithDefaults(NewFlowWizardPage.java:473)
at com.vaadin.designer2.eclipse.wizards.NewFlowWizardPage.initializeFields(NewFlowWizardPage.java:418)
at com.vaadin.designer2.eclipse.wizards.NewFlowWizardPage.createAdvancedControls(NewFlowWizardPage.java:354)
at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardNewFileCreationPage.createControl(WizardNewFileCreationPage.java:240)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:178)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:744)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.setWizard(WizardDialog.java:1182)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1235)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.lambda$3(WizardDialog.java:1223)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:67)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1223)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:918)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:469)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:263)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:283)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:317)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:251)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:485)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:389)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:142)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)

Following document, I am supposed to switch to another panel but nothing happen.

What am I doing wrong ?
I am using Eclipse Version: 2023-03

thanks for your help
Best regards
Genevieve

Comment: It seems this plugin does not work with the Maven support plugin of Eclipse (m2e) of version 2.x that is included in Eclipse since 2022-09 (in m2e 2.0 some deprecated things were removed). Make sure your Vaadin plugin is up to date, otherwise make sure it has been reported. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/73896834/6505250

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just to precise what I did :
- I install Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)
Build id: 20230309-1520

Comment: what I did :
- installed Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)
Build id: 20230309-1520 in the folder c:\Software\Eclipse\jee-2023-03
- created a maven project Spring Initializr https://start.spring.io with Vaadin dep
- I installed the Vaadin designer plugin in Eclipse 4.1.7 without error
- I imported the maven projet in Eclipse
- I added a folder src/views under the existing folder 'frontend'
- I right clicked on the views folder and select New -> Other -> Vaadin -> Vaadin 10+ Design
- I clicked 'next'
- nothing happen except above exception

Comment: My problem is nt related to the installation of the Vaadin designer plugin but to its usage.

the exception is related to not finding a specific method; so probably an incompatibility of the plugin with Eclpse 2023.3. But wher can I find information about which eclipse version to use ?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the **Vaadin Designer plugin** uses m2e, but **works** only with m2e 1.x, **not with m2e 2.x** because of [this change that has been introduced in m2e 2.0](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/commit/8b876a6748d8858578ee5894c40a872affc0e052#diff-31f2e51a0536514d2e606363296e464fa9353dedcde369bfd69c6d51c6479e0b). It seems that the Vaadin plugin has not specified an upper version range for m2e, so it can be installed even into an Eclipse IDE with m2e 2.x (which should not be possible), causing the error to occur at runtime.

See [**Vaadin Designer issue #2449 - *Cannot start designer (Eclipse Windows)***](https://github.com/vaadin/designer/issues/2449)

Comment: Hi @howlger,
I installed 2022-06 and I got the following error :

Comment: @GenevieveBreton What error do you get with which Eclipse 2022-06 IDE package when you do what? Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_. [Note that a bug fix is being worked on](https://github.com/vaadin/designer/issues/2449#issuecomment-1502395696).

Comment: Sorry i did not finish my previous message.
When I installed 2022-06 I got the same error.
I then installed 2021-12 and I am able to create a view through New->Others->Vaadin -> Vaadin 10+ Design.
However, when I open the view I have the following error :
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'vaadin' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\rbaud\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

Comment: I added in the pom.xml the dependency under dependencies :
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        </dependency>

but got the same error.

Comment: I also added :
  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
but always the same error
thansk for your help

Comment: Sorry that the workaround did not work, so I removed it from the answer. I'm not a Vaadin expert, nor a Vaadin user. For the new issue you might try right-clicking the project and choosing _Maven > Update Project..._ or if this does not help, you might ask on the Vaadin GitHub project.